# Ubuntu doesn't boot without a Monitor connected to a AMD 390

Tags: boot, amd-graphics

As the title says Ubuntu doesn't boot with AMD 390 with Hawaii chipset. The same system boots with AMD 290 with Hawaii and with AMD 380 with Tonga chipset without a monitor. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. For those who have a ASROCK motherboard with  one or more AMD 390 and the system will not boot without a monitor connected try to set the primary graphic adapter to ONBOARD in bios. After that my system boot headless without any problems and recognize the AMD 390.

Answer (score -1):

I would edit Grub with the following edits.

```
Sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

and edit the corresponding fields with...

GRUB_TIMEOUT=10

GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=$GRUB_TIMEOUT

This will allow the system to boot even if it fails during boot.

Then run

```
Sudo update-grub
```

This will work assuming I understood you correctly in that you are attempting to get the system to boot whether a monitor is connected or not.

Comment: Yes you understood me right, this maschine  is going to be headless (without a monitor). GRUB_TIMEOUT=10 was already in /etc/default/grub. I added the line  GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=$GRUB_TIMEOUT and sudo update-grub. But it didn't work.

Comment: Then the above solution should work. Please vote up when completed

Comment: I  have tried to add to /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"

Comment: Have you tried the solution above? It was implemented in 12.04 and works every time for me, doesn't matter about hardware

Comment: Yes i have tried the solution above.But it didn't work too.

Comment: I did not have luck with nomodeset myself

Comment: Don't forget to run sudo update-grub

Comment: No i had run sudo update-grub.

Comment: You added the recordfail option?

Comment: Where in grubenv ?

Comment: GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=$GRUB_TIMEOUT.  Add that below GRUB_TIMEOUT=10 and make sure to change grub timeout to 10 If it is set to 0

Comment: Then sudo update-grub and reboot then please vote up the answer

Comment: GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=$GRUB_TIMEOUT
I have it exactly in /etc/default/grub

Comment: and you updated grub and reboot and result?

Comment: yes i updated grub and  tried to reboot. without success

Comment: Are you on 14.04 or 16.04

Comment: oh i just saw that it is a Mint distro based on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS. Maybe that is the reason your solution didn't work?

Comment: Grub should be the same. Let me research and get back to ya

Comment: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=216642 take a look at that, I use X11 drivers, try uninstalling your amd driver

Comment: I don't believe that it is a driver issue. The maschine didn't boot at all. So it didn't load any drivers. And if i boot with monitor connected the gpu performance is great.

Comment: All out of ideas

Comment: Thanks anyway! This may help others with the same problem!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40918/discussion-on-answer-by-ilovekodi-ubuntu-doesnt-boot-without-a-monitor-connecte).