# Ubuntu Server 18.04 doesn't boot without monitor connected

Tags: boot, server, 18.04

I recently installed fresh Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS bionic and I am not able to get it to boot without display/monitor connected.
I have tried all help I could find on internet such as following two web pages, but no luck :
[Ubuntu doesn't boot without a Monitor connected to a AMD 390](https://askubuntu.com/questions/780975/ubuntu-doesnt-boot-without-a-monitor-connected-to-a-amd-390)
and 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2331323

Appreciate any help and clues from Gurus.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu (or any Linux for that matter) doesn't care if a monitor or keyboard is connected. The BIOS however does care. So you need to disable the wait/ask for keyboard settings in your BIOS

Comment: Thanks Simon, I will keep it in mind. I have been looking at my BIOS settings and haven't found anything which could be causing it like halt on error. I will update the question once I find a fix for it.

Comment: I apologize for getting back to my question after so long. I had lost it :)

Simon is absolutely correct. It had nothing to do with Ubuntu or Linux.
I was able to fix my Qotom Server BIOS settings and system was coming up fine over network without a monitor or keyboard.